# Python 3.5 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' using truncate filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to convert my Python Flask app from 2.7 to 3.5.  I have a simple CMS system using SQLAlchemy where my pages are displayed on the Index page with title and content (which are truncated). That is where my issue is happening.

It returns my pages as a list and my content as a string.  I tried to encode the "pages" but that returns another error because that is not allowed on a list object.

Error:

```
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 481, in do_truncate
    result = s[:length - len(end)].rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The route:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    pages = db.session.query(Pages).all()
    return render_template('index.html', title='Dashboard', pages=pages)
```

**index.html page**

```
{% for page in pages %}
<div>
    <a href="{{ url_for('view_page', page_id=page.id) }}"><h3>{{ page.title|truncate(150) }}</h3></a>
    <p>{{ page.content|truncate(450)|striptags }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So `page.title` is a bytes object. The `truncate` filter only works for `str` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `page.title` being a `bytes` object. You can't use `bytes.rsplit()` with a `str` value (which is what `truncate` does). The `truncate` filter only supports `str` Unicode values.

You'll have to make sure `pages.title` is a unicode `str` object instead. Do so either by decoding in the template, or by defining the `title` field to be a Unicode string rather than bytes in your model and database.

Decoding in the template can be done with:

```
{{ page.title.decode('utf8')|truncate(150) }}
```

provided your data is actually UTF-8 encoded.

This wasn't an issue in Python 2 as there bytestrings are silently converted to `unicode` strings as needed (and provided they can be decoded).